# Difference in performance or execution between single vs multiple, chained lambdas in Flux

Tags: influxdb, flux-influxdb

In Influx Flux, is there a technical difference (like in execution or performance) between setting a filter operation in a single statement vs. using multiple, chained statements?

For example, the single statement:

```js
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
  |> range(start: -1h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) =>
      r._measurement == "example-measurement" and
      r._field == "example-field" and
      r.tag == "example-tag"))
```

... versus using multiple, chained lambda's:

```js
from(bucket: "example-bucket")
  |> range(start: -1h)
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._measurement == "example-measurement")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r._field == "example-field")
  |> filter(fn: (r) => r.tag == "example-tag"))
```

Perhaps both operations are executed equally. But I cannot find canon in the docs on it, although the examples seem to prefer the first example.

I understand that logical operator OR isn't ideal in the second case. Let's assume for this question it's all AND.